# CakePHP Media Plugin not uploading

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to learn about [David Persson's CakePHP Media Plugin](https://github.com/davidpersson/media) through the included [tutorial](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/next/docs/TUTORIAL).

I get to the point where I can debug $this->data and it shows the 'file' array with the plugin's added keys (name, size and type) and I've added `var $actsAs = array('Media.Transfer');` to the model of my choice. The problem is, at this point when I submit the form, it should be uploading the file to the `app/webroot/media/transfers`, but it is not doing that.

Could the problem be that I haven't added any controller code or is that taken care of by asserting that `var $actsAs = array('Media.Transfer');`? Any other ideas? Do you need to see any code to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is app/webroot/media/transfers writable by apache or whatever web server you're running?

Comment: Yes, I've chmodded it to be 775.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also use the Media.Coupler behavior.

```
var $actsAs = array('Media.Transfer', 'Media.Coupler');
```

Comment: I tried that and had no luck. I think the Media.Coupler behavior is used for coupling files with db records anyway.

Comment: According to the tutorial, the file upload will not actually work without being coupled. While it may not completely solve the problem it looks like it would be part of the solution.  I'll take a look again tomorrow.

Comment: Has any of you figured out a solution to this?